# Already Platform App Builder, certified, why do I see a Force.com Developer - Summer '16 Release Exam option?

Tags: certification, app-builder, release-exam, platform-developer-1

If I am already a Salesforce Certified Platform App Builder, do I need to take the Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer - Summer '16 Release Exam?

Answer (score 2):

As you may be aware, In 2015 Salesforce had introduced newer certifications for Developer and Advanced Developers, which now is App builder and Platform Developer 1 & 2.

Quote from [Salesforce university](https://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/success-services/developer-certification-in-progress.jsp):

> Our Force.com credentials will begin retiring in July of 2017, so choose the best transition option for you. The retirement process for these credentials will be complete as of March 30, 2018.

It means the developer certification release exam is still valid until the certifications (401 and 501) are officially retired. So maybe after July 17 (Winter '17), it would be removed from webassessor as well.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I had the same question.. I am admin and advanced admin certified, as well developer, app builder and PD1 certified. Now Salesforce sent me mail to take release exams by March 24' 2017. I am confused as to if I have to take them or give it a pass as anyway they are going to retire. My question is in future if I would like to take advanced admin release exam, will Salesforce come back and say your admin is expired and you cannot take exam now. Looking for input from you since it seems like you touched on this subject. Thanks

Comment: Only developer and advanced developer exams are retiring. To maintain Admin and advanced admin one needs to complete admin release exam.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the information. I am curious as to what's the difference between taking and not taking the developer maintenance exam at this point. If SF is retiring cert, will it be anyway useful to take the maintenance exam and keep the credential.

Comment: If you have PD1, I would not pay a renewal to maintain your old Developer track certs. If you have App Builder but not PD1, then it might be worth renewing, especially if you work for a Partner. But probably better to go ahead and get PD1.